# How to connect ESC to serial?

Tags: blheli

I am looking for a way to access to configuration of Blheli-S firmware running on a Diatone Mamba F30Mini:
[image]

It seems possible using :

- [blheli-configurator](https://github.com/blheli-configurator/blheli-configurator/)
- [BLHeliSuite](https://github.com/bitdump/BLHeli)

There is explanation on different site about FC Passthrough. This seems to use connection to a Flight Controller.
As I am planning to use an Arduino nano to connect to the ESC, I am wondering how to make the connection.

Is it possible to connect more or less to connect the ESC to a PC ? or connecting through the arduino  ?

Comment: I haven't tried either method because I've always done it through the FC, but the method described in this PDF (https://flyingmodscom.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/blheli-programming-adapters.pdf) and this article (https://reefwing.medium.com/configuring-an-esc-with-blheli-firmware-using-an-arduino-uno-9b8e5dafc1c5) might help you here?

Comment: @ifconfig Thanks, document seems providing good information. I need to dig into, to understand the ESC side connection, in its documentation there is 8 pins (GND, VCC, motor1-4, Telemetry & Curr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to informations given by @ifconfig, using [BLHeliSuite](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/dx6kfaasyo24l/BLHeliSuite) connecting :

- GND to Arduino GND
- ESC1 to Arduino D11

It allow to upload to Arduino the "Arduino Bootloader"
[image]

Then selecting "ATMEL BLHeli Bootloader (USB/Com)", and go to "ESC Setup" tab
[image]

Finally quite straight-forward, with a tool that may be more user-friendly.